# Pass function to semantic ui clearable prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I have small portion of my app rendering a dropdown selection so users can view some brief information about library versions within the app.

The first dropdown is for the user to pick what they want view, for brevity I just added the relevant option for this question.

The second dropdown renders a fetched list of numbers pertaining to `deviceIds`. These `deviceIds` are fetched from a child class and then passed via props up to the parent class.

Now, In [Semantic-UI-React](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/), they have a dropdown module with a `clearable` prop which I am using on this dropdown populated with `deviceIds`. Below in `VersionNumber` class, you can see the props defined for the aforementioned dropdown.

The `clearable` prop lets the user remove the selected input from the dropdown. However, in my app when the input is removed it calls the `onChange` function which I do not want. I tried passing a custom change function to the `clearable` prop where I'm attempting to reset the state variable `deviceId` back to a undefined value if it's "cleared" by the user.

Is this possible? I'm pretty sure I'm taking the correct approach, but may be having an issue where the `onChange` function is firing before the `clearable` passed function.

I have a codesandbox that reproduces [this problem here](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-mountain-ixih6).

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";

import {
  Dropdown,
  Form,
  Divider,
  Input,
  Message,
  Loader
} from "semantic-ui-react";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      viewSelection: "",
      deviceId: "",
      versionNum: "",
      isLoading: true
    };
  }

  handleViewSelection = (e, { value }) => {
    this.setState({ viewSelection: value }, () => {
      console.log("view election --> ", this.state.viewSelection);
    });
  };

  onDeviceIdChange = async (e, { value }) => {
    console.log("device id value -->", value);
    this.setState({ deviceId: value }, () => {
      console.log(
        "deviceId value updated to state on select -->",
        this.state.deviceId
      );
    });
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`/deviceId/${value}`);
      const version = data.data.versionNumber;
      this.setState({ versionNum: version.version, isLoading: false }, () => {
        console.log("callback from admin version fetch", this.state.versionNum);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(Error(`Error getting the selected deviceId ${error.message}`));
    }
  };

  handleClear = () => {
    this.setState({ deviceId: "" }, () => {
      console.log("handleClear function fired");
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { viewSelection, deviceId, versionNum, isLoading } = this.state;
    return (
      <div
        style={{ display: "flex", minHeight: "100vh", flexDirection: "column" }}
      >
        <div style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <div
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "column",
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
              flex: "1"
            }}
          >
            <div style={{ width: "1000px" }}>
              <Divider style={{ marginTop: "7em" }} horizontal>
                View Data
              </Divider>
              <Message style={{ marginTop: "2em" }} info>
                <Message.Header>
                  Want to see more specific information? Log in &nbsp;
                  <a href="/">here</a>.
                </Message.Header>
              </Message>
              <Form.Field style={{ marginTop: "2em" }}>
                <label>Select data to view</label>
                <Dropdown
                  scrolling
                  placeholder="Pick an option"
                  value={viewSelection}
                  fluid
                  selection
                  multiple={false}
                  search
                  options={viewOptions}
                  onChange={this.handleViewSelection}
                />
              </Form.Field>

              {this.state.viewSelection && (
                <div style={{ marginTop: "2em" }}>
                  {viewSelection && viewSelection === "versionNumber" ? (
                    <>
                      <VersionNumber
                        onDeviceIdChange={this.onDeviceIdChange}
                        deviceId={deviceId}
                        handleClear={this.handleClear}
                      />
                      <div>
                        <label style={{ display: "block", marginTop: "2em" }}>
                          Version Number
                        </label>
                        {isLoading ? (
                          <Loader active inline="centered" />
                        ) : (
                          <Input value={versionNum} fluid readOnly />
                        )}
                      </div>
                    </>
                  ) : null}
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class VersionNumber extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      deviceId: "",
      deviceIds: []
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.getDeviceIds();
  }

  getDeviceIds = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get("/deviceIds");
      console.log("device IDs --> ", data);
      const deviceIds = data.data.deviceIds;
      this.setState(
        {
          deviceIds: deviceIds
        },
        () => {
          console.log(
            "setState callback with updatesd deviceIds state -->",
            this.state.deviceIds
          );
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(Error(`Error getting deviceIds: ${error.message}`));
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { onDeviceIdChange, deviceId, handleClear } = this.props;
    const { deviceIds } = this.state;

    return (
      <Form.Field required>
        <label style={{ display: "block" }}>Device Id</label>
        <Dropdown
          id="deviceId"
          value={deviceId}
          onChange={onDeviceIdChange}
          selection
          fluid
          placeholder="Please select an device id"
          clearable={handleClear}
          options={deviceIds.map(id => {
            return {
              text: id.id,
              value: id.id,
              key: id.id
            };
          })}
          style={{ marginTop: ".33", marginBottom: "2em" }}
        />
      </Form.Field>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: `clearable` prop takes a `boolean` value not a function. Why not add a condition in your `onChange` to figure out the clearable invocation and execute accordingly?

Comment: I wasn't sure if there was a way around providing more than just a boolean, but I figured there was not. Based off what condition, how can I determine that `clearable` has been invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clearable` prop expects a `boolean` value. You can change your `onChange` callback to consider the scenario where the `value` is going to be passed in as `null / undefined`

The function can be modified as below to reset the `deviceId` and prevent the API call

```
onDeviceIdChange = async (e, { value }) => {

  // VALUE WILL BE PASSED IN AS "" WHEN THE CLEAR OPTION IS CLICKED
  console.log("device id value -->", value);
  this.setState({ deviceId: value }, () => {
    console.log(
      "deviceId value updated to state on select -->",
      this.state.deviceId
    );
  });

  // THIS IS THE CONDITION TO CATCH THE CLEARABLE INVOCATION
  if(!value) {
    this.handleClear();
    return;
  } 

  ...
};
```

`if(!value) return;` Think of this condition as the execution that the clearable option will invoke. You can invoke anything before the return to ensure that your application handles the clear option in the way you expect it to.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. However, when the `deviceId` is cleared from the dropdown, the `VersionNumber` label and the previous value for it still persists in the view. I guess I would need to set `isLoading` to true when the clearable prop is invoked?

Comment: You just need to set the state variables for them accordingly. Inside the `if(!value)` you can add any custom execution based on the behaviour you want. It's like `if(!value) this.handleClear(); return;`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.